# Creating a mosaic of thumbnails with OpenCV 3 and numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I have a list of thumbnails all of the same size and I want to show them as a mosaic with a given width. The idea is to create a single image for each row with shape `(thumb_height, thumb_width*width, 3)` and then concatenate them all together by obtaining a single image. Now, if the width is not a divisor of the number of thumbnails the last row will miss some images. The idea is to fill the gap with a black placeholder. Here's the code:

```
def show_images_mosaic(images, width):
    rows = []
    for i in range(0, len(images), width):
        rows.append(np.concatenate(images[i: i + width], axis=1))

    if len(rows) > 1:
        last_row = rows[-1]

        height = images[0].shape[0]
        last_row_width = last_row.shape[1]
        expected_width = rows[0].shape[1]

        if last_row_width < expected_width:
            filler = np.zeros((height, expected_width - last_row_width, 3))
            rows[-1] = np.concatenate((last_row, filler), axis=1)
        else:
            filler = None

    mosaic = np.concatenate(rows, axis=0)
    cv2.imshow('Mosaic', mosaic)

    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        cv2.imshow('Row' + str(i), row)

    cv2.imshow('LastRowUnfilled', last_row)
    if filler is not None:
        cv2.imshow('Filler', filler)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This code works great if `width` is a divisor of the number of thumbnails. But for some reason it breaks when I have to fill the last row. The weird thing is that it doesn't break only the last row, but it breaks the whole image and I really can't understand why. Additionally the single rows except for the last one are correctly shown, but the whole mosaic is broken as if the last row affects the whole image.

Comment: Can you show an example of broken mosaic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem could be related to the fact that your thumbnails are 8-bit images.

By default `np.zeros` creates an array of type `np.float64`. So when you concatenate your filler with your last row and then with the whole mosaic, you end up with an array that contains values up to 255 but with `dtype=np.float64`. OpenCV expects float images to be in range `[0, 1]`.

To correct it, declare your filler like this:

```
filler = np.zeros((height, expected_width - last_row_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

N.B: If you save your mosaic to disk, you shouldn't see a problem. It's only `imshow` that's broken if that is indeed the issue.

Comment: Adding `dtype=np.uint8` solved the problem! And also `imshow` works! thanks @Sunreef